# How can we extract name of the outer function from a sub function?

Tags: r

I have three functions in 'R':

```
## Inner Function
funcA <- function(A){
  return(A + 1)
}

## Outer Function 1
funcB <- function(B){
  funcA(B)
}

## Outer Function 2
funcC <- function(C){
  funcA(C)
}
```

What I want to do is -

```
## Inner Function
funcA <- function(A){
  if (called from funcB()){
    x = 1
  }else if(called from funcC()){
    x = 2
  }
  return(A + x)
}
```

How can I know which outer function called funcA from inside of funcA?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give a character string containing the name of the calling function:

```
as.character(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe() - 1]][[1]])
```

If at all feasible in order to improve modularity I would not do this and instead,  pass an argument to `funcA` which determines how it acts or perhaps it would be possible to use S3 and pass objects of different classes to `funcA`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. I second your idea on passing argument to funcA, but wanted to learn if this was possible. Thanks again.